# Where does the name SignalR come from?

Tags: c#, signalr

Neither wikipedia nor the SignalR homepage explain its name.

Perhaps you know where it comes from?

Comment: Does that really matter?

Comment: @LexLi is it illegal to be curious about the ethymology of something?

Comment: I'm surprised that a user with your reputation membership record length would ask such an off topic question.  It is *most likely* going to attract opinion-based responses.  The only people who would truly be able to help you would be David Fowler and maybe Damian Edwards.  Hitting them up on email or Twitter would probably be more productive.

Comment: @DavidL I don't think it's a option-based quesiton at all. either a name has a clear history or it hasn't. there is nothing to quarrel about.

Comment: There's certainly a great deal to quarrel about since only one person can give a definitive answer (David Fowler), unless he also wrote it down somewhere and I haven't been able to find a post like that.

Comment: @t3chb0t The answer you did get so far is unverifiable though, and I wouldn't be surprised if unverifiable answers are all you'll get.

Comment: @hvd that's fine too. if only the author knows the history of the name so be it :-) but since so many people use it I thought some already might have found this out but DavidL is probably right that in this case I should ask the author himself

Comment: @DavidL by the way the github page says that quesitons about SignalR can also be asked here with the appropriate tag so it's very probable that the author might see it unless he is no longer involved in the project but I'm afraid it'll get closed before anyone else will have the chance to provide the correct answer

Answer (score 9):

> **What is Signal R**
>
> Signals are used for communication (e.g. analog and digital). **R stands
>   for real-time.** Real-time web refers the ability to have server code
>   push content to the connected clients instantly. Signal R in short
>   refers to Real-time application communication

From [Signal R - A Real-Time Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/810328/Signal-R-A-Real-Time-Application)

The closest to anything official I can find is on the [github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/fa864e866bea4737dbd888f993892694f2f6b1a6/xamarin/SignalRPackage/component/GettingStarted.md) which states:

> **ASP.NET SignalR** 
>   Async **signaling** library for .NET to help build
>   **real-time**, multi-user interactive web applications

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

The [main site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) says, "real time" numerous times in the opening paragraph, but comes short of saying `R == RealTime`:

> **What is SignalR?**
>
> ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies
>   the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications.
>   Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push
>   content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather
>   than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

There's plenty of other anecdotal mentions on the blogsphere, e.g. [Overview of SignalR](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/302f8f/overview-of-signalr/).

I have also asked for confirmation on the SignalR teams [JabbR](https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr).

Comment: The author of that article doesn't have a background that suggests association with the development of SignalR, nor any sources for their definition.  It certainly could be correct but that doesn't make it credible.

Comment: Your link doesn't appear to provide any support for this claim, it merely states it as an indisputable fact. What makes the author trustworthy?

Comment: This sounds plausible but not proven yet.

Comment: Have you received any confirmation yet?